# Finding cdf of difference of two random variables from a joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have that:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
8xy,  & \text{if $0<y<x<1$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to solve for the cdf of a random variable $W$, where $W = X - Y$. I've written down that I'm trying to solve for $F_W(w) = P(W\le w) = P(X - Y\le w)$, which I'm expressing as:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_{x-w}^x 8xy \;dy \right) dx $$

I'm pretty certain that my limits are off, but my rationale is that the inner integral is solving over the support of $Y$, while the outer integral is solving over the support of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer has been corrected (again, and again) to respond to comments by @AndréNicolas.**

You method is fine, but you're right that one of the limits are wrong (and not both, as I originally wrote).

The support of the joint distribution is a triangle, with verticies at $\langle 0,0\rangle$, $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$.  The probability that $X-Y\leq w$ is the (double) integral of the joint pdf *except* over some smaller triangle where $X-Y$ is large (i.e. where $x-y$ is a long way from the line $y=x$).  The resulting area is a trapezoid: to find the cdf, you just need to find the limits of integration that describe this trapezoid.

For $w\in [0,1]$, this smaller triangle will be similar to the big triangle: it will be a right angle isosceles triangle with its apex at $\langle 1,0\rangle$.  The hypotenuse of the triangle will lie on the line $x-y=w$, or $y=x-w$.  So, for the trapezoid, the $y$ variable will be integrated from $0$ to $x$ for values of $x$ below $w$ and from $x-w$ to $x$ for values of the $x$ between $w$ and $1$.  The cdf, expressed as an integral is therefore:
$$F_W(w)=\left\{\begin{array}{1cl}
0 & \textrm{if} & w<0 \\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x-w,0\}}^{x}8xy \, \textrm{d}y \, \textrm{d}x & \textrm{if} & 0\leq w \leq 1 \\
1 & \textrm{if} & 1<w
\end{array}\right.$$

As noted in the long comment thread below, it is simpler to avoid that unpleasant "$\max$" operator and take one minus the integral over the triangle instead:

\begin{eqnarray}
& & \int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x-w,0\}}^{x}8xy\,\textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x+\int_{w}^{1}\int_{0}^{x-w}8xy\,\textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x \\
& =& \int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x-w,0\}}^{x}8xy\,\textrm{d}y\, \textrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\max\{x-w,0\}}8xy\, \textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x \\
& = & \int_{w}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}8xy \, \textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x \\
& = & 1.\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks! Still running into some problems, though.

I'm getting $(-1/3 * (w-1)^3 * (w+3))$ as my CDF if $0 \le w \le 1$. Problem is, then I'm getting $F_W(1) = 0$. Any idea why?

Comment: There is a little mistake in the setup. The probability that $W\le w$ is not the given integral, it is the integral over the **rest** of the basic triangle, it is the integral over a trapezoid. Easy fix, the cdf is $1$ minus the integral of the answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Gotcha. I see it now. Would it be too complicated to try and express the capture the trapezoid through the double integral limits?

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas for pointing out my error.  I have made the necessary corrections.

Comment: The answer above was perfectly good, except that it gave $1-F_W(w)$. If you draw a picture (essential) you will see that if we want to write down an integral directly for the cdf, we want to integrate over the part of the square which is between the lines $y=x$ and $y=x-w$. Then we have to break up the integral into two parts, or make a change of variable. The calculation of the complement, i.e. integrating over the little triangle, is easier.

Comment: @Unwisdom: I think modifying the previous method (so $1$ minus the integral over the little triangle) is better. Your current integral misses the piece with $x$ between $0$ and $w$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yep, I have those two lines $y=x$ and $y=x-w$, but didn't think about breaking up the integral. Calculating the complement (?) -- the little triangle -- certainly seems easier.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you both! Biggest thing was my seeing the triangle correctly -- I see that now.

Comment: You are welcome. I cannot solve this kind of problem (or at least I cannot *know* that I am right) without drawing a picture. And with the proper picture, the answer writes itself.

Comment: And thanks to @AndréNicolas from me too!  I tried doing it without a picture in front of me, and paid the price.  I feel embarrassed, but at least (I think) it's right now.  Sorry about my many errors!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using automated tools.

Given: random variables $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

You seek the cdf of $W=X-Y$, namely $P(W<w) = P(X-Y<w)$:

[image]

All done.

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.

Comment: Edit: never mind, work proxy blocked the images. I see them now.